# Retaining Formatting in Word VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, clipboard

We have a VSTO Word add-in where users input text into a RichTextContentControl. This input is modified elsewhere and returned to the rich text control, but as the formatting information (most importantly bullet points) are not stored in the string the formatting is lost.

Our best-idea for a solution currently is to copy to the clipboard and paste it back into the rich text control in plain text format, thus converting the bullet points to the unicode •, as so:

```
richTextControl.Range.Copy();
richTextControl.Range.Text = "";
richTextControl.Range.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatPlainText);
```

This isn't a good solution though, as we don't want to be overwriting the user's clipboard.

Is there a better way?